# How to enumerate privileges of a given AD Domain user?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am currently working on a non-privileged Powershell of a domain joined host, trying to enumerate all privileges of one AD user.

After doing some research, I understood there is no  straight-forward way to view the privileges assigned to a user account via direct / indirect membership in groups and organisational units.

`whoami / priv` for the logged on user also gives no exhaustive list of all assigned privileges.

Furthermore, trying to run AccessChk.exe from Microsoft's Sysinternals Suite using `accesschk [user] -a *` fails due to missing admin privileges.

Is there any other way to list all privileges assigned to a given user acccount?

Comment: `whoami / priv for the logged on user also gives no exhaustive list of all assigned privileges.` What assigned privileges do you claim are missing? We're not mind readers.

Comment: AccessChk can provide a more comprehensive listing of User Privileges than `whoami /priv`. Please have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607389/how-to-view-user-privileges-using-windows-cmd). But thanks for the downvote anyway!

Comment: You say it doesn't provide a full list, but you provide no  example of a missing privilege or right. Also you are asking for something that can be done as a normal user but this is something that implicitly requires administrator-level access.